# Getting string value between two chacter with random string in the middle

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have few HTML line like this

```
<div class="itemA" attr="abc">VALUE I NEED TO GET</div>
<div class="itemA" data-attr="def">VALUE I NEED TO GET</div>
<div class="itemA" something-else="xyz">VALUE I NEED TO GET</div>
<div class="itemA" other="123">VALUE I NEED TO GET</div>
<div class="itemB">VALUE I DONT NEED TO GET</div>
<div class="itemB">VALUE I DONT NEED TO GET</div>
```

I know the way to get string value between two character in regular expression be like:

```
(?<=[char1]).*?(?=[char2])")
```

When I use this

```
Regex.Matches([HTML_ABOVE], @"(?<=class=""itemA"")(.*?)(?=</div>)")
```

Return be like:

```
attr="abc">VALUE I NEED TO GET
data-attr="def">VALUE I NEED TO GET
something-else="xyz">VALUE I NEED TO GET
other="123">VALUE I NEED TO GET
```

Is there anyway to ignore or remove pre-characters ?

Comment: I would google for a HTML parsing framework and using this ;)

Comment: [Obligatory link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2307070) about why ṫ̨̗̺̭̮̞̗̜̮̗̙̫̺̖̭̯͊ͨ̌͒̍͘͘͟͝h̸͓̩̙͙̻̗͔̞̘̟̩̯͋͑͂͐a̴̧ͨ́ͭ͒ͯ̓͐̇̃ͥ͢҉‌​̨̳̜̤͍͖t̵̳̳͕͉͋̓͐ͦͬ̈́̀̚‌ is a bad idea

Comment: As long as it is well-formed XML you could try to read it as XML

Comment: Or use `<div class="item"[^>]+>(.*?)(?=<\/div>)` if you want your code to work most of the time, but not everytime

Comment: I use Regex be cause it very quick to setup, also I only need few value from the whole html page

Comment: If you are parsing changeable HTML or have difficult html node scenarios, then yes use the html agility pack, it is the way to go. But if you have static and sane html and can easily scoop up data via regex, use regex. People do not like to offer regex solutions because they haven't take the time to learn the pattern matching and because of that they `vote` down any regex question on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the *not in set* capture `[^ ]+` instead to find the text. So I would change it to be

```
(?<=>)([^<]+)
```

which says to match, but not consume/capture a `>`. Then once found consume all text which is not a `<`.

Due to the html language and that its text will span lines, one will get space characters such as `\r\n` which will yield blank matches. So I would add to the pattern `(?![\r\n])..` to not match `?!` and stop if it sees such spaces.

```
(?<=>)(?![\r\n])([^<]+)
```

Here is my C# example

```
string data = @"<div class=""item"" attr=""abc"">VALUE I NEED TO GET</div>
<div class=""item"" data-attr=""def"">VALUE I NEED TO GET</div>
<div class=""item"" something-else=""xyz"">VALUE I NEED TO GET</div>
<div class=""item"" other=""123"">VALUE I NEED TO GET</div>";

Regex.Matches(data, @"(?<=>)(?![\r\n])([^<]+)")
     .OfType<Match>()
     .Select(itm => itm.Groups[1].Value);
```

Which returns four matches:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but i don't think it works if there are other tag inside the data, it will grab all other value inside > <

Comment: @S.A True, but you didn't provide that as a situation which needed to be considered. Are there others?

Comment: I updated to add more case, hope it will help to make my purpose clearer

Comment: @S.A It appears by your latest example that to get just the specific strings, you would need to add more to the lookbehind `(?<= {...})` to get the specific data, but it should work. If it gets more complicated, the node acquisition via attributes, then you may want to look into using the html agility pack.

Comment: Yes, the {...} is actually which I haven't known yet, not sure what to put in there so the regular can skip everything until character ">"

Comment: @S.A This seems to work for me `(?<=itemA.+?>)`. The `.+?` says match as little as possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you search in your NuGet package Manager for [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), you will get a nice tool, which will do all the parsing for you. Then you do not Need the RegEx.